# Python matplotlib subplots: putting horizontal bar charts side by side and unwanted numerical labels on axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, subplot

Consider the following fake data:

```
fake_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"index": ["A", "B", "C"], 0: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 1: [2, 4, 6], 2: [1, 3, 5]}
)
fake_data.set_index("index")
```

I want to plot a sequence of horizontal bar charts, one row by three columns. The y axis of each bar chart contains the categorical variables `A`, `B` and `C`. The x axis of each bar chart should be numerical.

I have tried the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex = True, sharey = True, figsize = (6, 8), frameon = False)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
fake_data[0].plot.barh()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
fake_data[1].plot.barh()
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
fake_data[2].plot.barh()
```

The output is:

[image: The output of the above code]

I've tried adjusting the axes labels and ticks by modifying the above code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex = True, sharey = True, figsize = (6, 8), frameon = False)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
fake_data[0].plot.barh()
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
fake_data[1].plot.barh()
ax2.set_xticks([])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
fake_data[2].plot.barh()
```

The output is:

[image: The output of the preceding block of code]

As you can see, the categorical labels are now gone.

My questions are:

1. How can I get rid of the numerical ticks / labels on the y axis on the leftmost horizontal bar chart, given that the y axis is supposed to have a categorical variable?
2. How can I get rid of the labels and ticks and the y-axis name "index" on the second and third bar charts?
3. Similarly to (1), how can I get rid of the numerical ticks / labels on the x axis that are overlapping with the correct ticks / labels?
4. How can I make all the x axes of the horizontal bar charts on the same scale, such that the first (leftmost) horizontal bar chart is of the order of a tenth of the second and third bar charts?

Comment: As you are using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` the subplots are already created. You should remove `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)` (which creates another subplot at the same spot)  and add the ax to `fake_data[0].plot.barh(ax=ax[0])`.

Comment: You should also set `fake_data = fake_data.set_index('index')`, to have the index being really the index instead of a separate column.

Comment: Many thanks. How does it work if I want to use a loop to add subplots one by one? I set a 2 by 3 subplot and used for i in range(6) loop, then the error returned 'IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3'

Comment: When you have a 2D array of axes, you can do `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, ...)` followed by `for i, ax in zip(range(6), axes.flatten(): ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already created your `axes` using `plt.subplots`. You can pass them to each `pd.Series.plot` method and it will fix your problems:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(
    1, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 8), frameon=False
)
fake_data[0].plot.barh(ax=ax1)
fake_data[1].plot.barh(ax=ax2)
fake_data[2].plot.barh(ax=ax3)
```

[image]